# Why doesn't work return? Code works, but test fails. #Different between print() and return

Tags: python-3.x, return

`prim(n)`  is a function that I wrote, it checks if  a number  `n`  is prim.
`prim_2(n)` does return a list of all primes untill n.

```
prim_liste = []
def prim_2(n):
    if n == 1:
        prim_liste.reverse()
        print(prim_liste)  # return prim_liste doesn't work. 
    elif n > 1: 
        if prim(n) == "Is prim":
            prim_liste.append(n)
            prim_2(n-1)                
        elif prim(n) == "Is not prim":
            prim_2(n-1)
```

If I replace  `print(prim_liste)`  with  `return prim_liste`, my tests fails anyway.

> prim_2(5) == [2, 3, 5]

It does return False, although my code works.

When I ran my program with`return prim_liste`, it happened nothing.
With `print(prim_liste)` it does"return" the right result.

Thank you for help! :) Sorry for my bad English and this confusing post.

Comment: did you see the prime list printed out?  you sure prim(n) returns what you expected?

Comment: yeah i saw it. the function works like a wanted, because of that i was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `return prim_2(n-1)` in the recursion also, otherwise the function doesn't return anything for anything else than 1.

The single return in one case doesn't return from the whole recursion, only from that stage and all other calls to the function must also return a value.

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I spend so much time to write this code and
It was so frustrating that I couldn't figure it why my test fails.
I'm very at the beginning of coding and your answer helped me to understand what was the problem.
I often were unsure when to use return and how to use it in recursion. 
I think, I understand it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should see the prim list printed out in your codes. if not, prim() must have something wrong.  if you need prim_2() to return the prime list, you need do the following.

```
prim_liste = []

def prim_2(n):
    if n == 1:
        prim_liste.reverse()
        return prim_liste   
    elif n > 1: 
        if prim(n) == "Is prim":
            prim_liste.append(n)
        # test for "Is not prim" is not necessary.
        return prim_2(n-1)  # be sure to return what prim_2() returns
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I didn't used return in the recursion.
So it couldn't give me a result.
With print() it showed me the result, but the test could not work so, because without using return the function gives only None back.
Because of that all my tests fail, although it the code seemed to be correct.

```
prim_liste = []
def prim_2(n):
    if n == 1:
        prim_liste.reverse()
        return prim_liste     
    elif n > 1: 
        if prim(n) == "Is prim":
            prim_liste.append(n)
            return prim_2(n-1)                
    else:
        return prim_2(n-1)
```